# How to get value of sub-item in a listview in android studio

Tags: android, android-listview

I am making a list of contacts. The contact number is a sum item in the list. If user clicks the phone button on that item then the number is called.
How to get the number? It is a sub-item in the list.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // Get the selected item text from ListView
                String selectedItem = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"item is"+selectedItem,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

I am only able to get the Item Value. Not the subItem

Comment: Tell me if I am right. You have a list in which number is a subitem in the list item. You are able to access the list items but not the number subitem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a method on the adapter to return the subItem from the item List

without the code it is hard to give more details.